Pretty good measurement for pure state discrimination
Consider the setting of discriminating between $m$ pure states $|\psi_1\rangle, \dots |\psi_m\rangle$ in the setting of worst-case error. There is a simple algorithm using sequential measurements which solves this problem with the following worst-case guarantee: given as input the state $|\psi_i\rangle$, the algorithm correctly identifies it except with probability  at most $O(1) \sum_{j \neq i} \vert \langle \psi_j \vert \psi_i \rangle \vert^2 \leq m F^2$ where $F = \max_{j \neq i}F(\psi_j, \psi_i) = \max_{j \neq i} \vert \langle \psi_j \vert \psi_i \rangle \vert$.
If we analyze this same problem using the pretty good measurement, this paper shows that the Pretty Good Measurement (PGM) defined by $S = \sum_{j=1}^m |\psi_j \rangle\langle \psi_j|$, then setting our POVM elements to be $E_j = S^{-1/2} |\psi_j \rangle\langle \psi_j |S^{-1/2}$ can correctly identify the state except with error at most $m\cdot F$. This is worse than the sequential measurement argument, but in principle the PGM should be able to achieve the same low error probability. Does anyone know of a better way or at least an approach to try to prove the better bound?

Why should the pretty good measurement achieve the same error probability? It's pretty good, not optimal.

The PGM has success rate $P_\text{OPT} \geq P_\text{PGM} \geq P_\text{OPT}^2$. If $P_\text{OPT} = 1 - \varepsilon$, then $P_\text{OPT}^2 \sim 1 - 2\varepsilon$, so up to constant factors the PGM should do optimally. However, the analysis I mention in the question does not achieve this. So, it seems like there should be a more careful analysis which does show that it achieves this bound.

Maybe it does for small $F$, but in the general case $F$ can be 1.

right, so let's assume we are working in the case of small F. There should be a way to analyze this and get the optimal bound (up to a constant factor), I'd like to figure out how to do this

I think the problem comes from your analysis of the sequential measurements algorithm.  I think we can just consider an adaptation of the example of the anti-Zeno effect from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.03236.
Let's take our initial state to be $|0\rangle$, and say we go to measure the PVM corresponding to the state $\sin(\frac{\pi k}{2n})|0\rangle + \cos(\frac{\pi k}{2n})|1\rangle$ for k ranging from 1 to (say) $\sqrt{n}$, and then say that the algorithm measures $|0\rangle$ after that.  Being a little loose, taking $\sin^2(\frac{\pi k}{2n}) \approx (\frac{\pi k}{2n})^2$, we see that the the sum of squared fidelities is something like $1/n$ (the squared fidelity puts a $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in the denominator, and I'm summing from $k = 1$ to $\sqrt{n}$, which puts a $O(n)$ on the numerator), but the probability that the algorithm gets the wrong answer is at least $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, since at the end (if we haven't accepted at the end), we've rotated the state to $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}})|0\rangle + \cos(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}})|1\rangle$, and $\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}) \approx (1 - \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}})^2 \approx 1 - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}$.
I guess all this to say that I don't think that the sequential measurement you described does as well as you originally stated, so the error you put for the PGM is probably optimal.  You can probability randomize the ordering of the measurements (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.09155), which gets rid of the anti-Zeno effect I used in this example, maybe that gets a similar success probability to the PGM, but I haven't worked it out.
